# Is it technically possible to play Chopin`s op. 10 No 1 etude at 176 bpm on Casio PX-160 piano?

Tags: piano, key, digital-piano, action

Is it technically possible to play Chopin`s op. 10 No 1 etude at 176 bpm on Casio PX-160 piano?

Comment: Curious - is a Casio PX-160 piano the only keyboard instrument you have access to?

Comment: @player777 Although the question that you kept is the most important to you, it's kind of a shame since some of the deleted ones were easier to answer. I'm not familiar with the exact model and am not a pianist, but I imagine that a keyboard's action limits the tempo first for repeated notes, and in a quick scan of the score I don't notice those. 176 bpm x 4 notes per beat / 60 = 11.7 notes per second. It sounds like a tempo that would challenge the performer's ability, but in my opinion ought to be possible on a digital piano with good action. (Whether it's _fun_ or _useful_, now...

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but might help: I have a Kawai CE 220 digital piano, which I like very much for its realistic action. I'm able to repeat a single pitch in 16th notes on it at 125 bpm. I assume that means, if I had the technique, I could play arpeggios much faster.

Comment: What problems do you expect to run into?

Comment: Key action response is definitely slower than on Roland FP and acoustic Kawai. I went to the piano shop and tried. Sadly have no Steinway or similar. Can you play that at 176 on Casio PX? I can`t overcome 155 bpm with my current level of technique. Acoustic pianos in our local music shops have a faster key response and easier action. I thought Casio was better.

Comment: Just following up a year later ... was the answer helpful? Is more information needed?

Answer (score 4):

#### TL;DR

Yes

---

<sub>*Caveat: I have not been able to access a Casio PX-160 to positively confirm this answer.*</sub>

#### Is it possible to play Chopin's Etude Op. 10 No. 1 at 176bpm?

Yes. It requires outstanding technique, but it can be done.

#### Can it be done on a Casio PX-160?

Yes. The only technical issue would be the small handful of repeated notes. For example, the first two notes of the piece:

[image: Chopin Op. 10, No. 1, opening notes repeat C3]

The execution of these repeated notes would test any keyboard's response time. However, the PX-160 is of good enough quality, this should not be an issue.

There would likely be *musical* issues, as opposed to issues of pure technique. Here the main issue would be the dynamic range of the keyboard. Can it produce the kind of subtle dynamic shading of an acoustic piano or higher-end keyboard? Probably not. But the question is about technical possibility, so this issue can be set aside.

#### Is 176bpm the "right" speed in the first place?

Metronome markings from that era of music are notoriously unreliable. And one also has to remember that pianos of that era had a much lighter touch, the key depths were shallower, and the overall power in terms of volume and sustain were lower compared to modern instruments. All of those factors would facilitate fast playing in comparison to heavier-action modern pianos. Even taking 176 as definitively correct, it must be reconsidered in modern terms.

Comment: Not to mention, the idea of playing _metronomically_ is one to challenge, even in such a moto-perpetuo-style piece. A metronome marking is a reference point, but doesn't mean that you are to play metronomically, especially when the words "Chopin" and "rubato" have such an entangled relationship.

Comment: @AndyBonner It has been famously noted that the rubato associated with Chopin is a "give and take" in time. So if you were to apply rubato on this piece (played at ~176 bpm), you might need the key action to be able to tolerate, say, ~200 bpm.